# Comma separated words regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I'm having some issues while trying to parse expression such as the following:

```
word1, word2[a,b,c],   word3, ..., wordN
```

I'd like to get the following groups:

```
g1: word1
g2: word2[a,b,c]
g3: word3
```

Please note that the [.+] is optional, the regular expression must be able to match expressions like the following the following:

```
word1,word2,word3
word1[a,b,c],word2,word3
word1[a,b,c],word2[e,f,g],word3
word1[a,b,c],word2[e,f,g],word3[i,j,l]
```

I did some attempts but I can't find the way to correctly separate the groups.

Comment: You might want to consider using some sort of parser for this.  Commas can be nested, and regex doesn't handle nested structure very well.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to use only std python stuff so I don't want to depend on 3rd party parsers :(

Comment: Can those brackets be nested? Otherwise good old `,(?![^[]*\])` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being this seems to be working:

```
import re
rgx = re.compile("(\w+(\[.*?\])*).*?,?")
[key for key, val in rgx.findall("word1, word2[a,b,[c,,,]],     word,3")]

# this regex starts by looking for alpha numberic characters with \w+
# then within that it looks if a `[` is present then till we encounter end of bracket ']' consider everything (\[.*?\])*.
# the output of this is a tuple as ('word2[a,b,c]', '[a,b,c]')
# we iterate over the tuple and take only the 1st values in the tuple
```

output:

```
['word1', 'word2[a,b,[c,,,]', 'word', '3']
```

another example

```
[key for key, val in rgx.findall("word1[bbbb,cccc],word2[bbbb,cccc] ")]
```

output:

```
['word1[bbbb,cccc]', 'word2[bbbb,cccc]']
```

PS: still regexing to improve it.

Comment: Thanks sir. Your solution seems  to work correctly. Plz, could you provide some more explanation on it specially the regex itself. I can't see where the "," separated part is included/processed?

Comment: @redobot added explanation. Let me know if more description is needed.

Comment: Thank you very  much. Your solution is good, just to add that it's not forcing the separator to be a comma (for me it's OK), I tested the code with other separators (: for instance) and it works also. I'll accept it as solution even though it would be good to highlight this in the answer. Thanks again :)

Comment: @redobot Issues might occur if your word doesn't consist of word characters entirely or if brackets can be nested (you haven't answered my comment concerning this yet)

Comment: Sorry for that. The brackets cannot be nested. and the words can only have alphanumeric characters.

Comment: @redobot fixed for most cases. check it out now. you should not have problems with inner brackets and `,s`

Comment: Your previous version is Ok since the brackets could not be nested. The comma separator forcing is desirable but it's not a must.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this regex on https://regex101.com, and pasted your expressions into the "test strings" box.

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\[.*\])?),([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\[.*\])?),([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\[.*\])?)$/gm
```

Each word is separated by a comma, and of the form:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\[.*\])?)
```

Explanation:

```
(
  [a-zA-Z0-9]+ # one or more alphanumeric characters (could use \w)
  (?:\[.*\])? # an optional sequence surrounded by []s. (?: ) means a non-capturing group
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm using http://pythex.org/ to test it with the following expression and it doesn't seem to work: word1[bbbb,cccc],word2[bbbb,cccc]

Comment: Oh, I see your post says this is for N words - I thought it was for exactly 3 words.

Comment: Yes, my fault. I just added this to avoid this confusion.  Thanks for your reply anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.split` to split only on commas, that are outside of brackets. This can be determinded by the fact, that those commas will never match a closing bracket before the opening one (using a negative lookahead). This trick is only possible with non-nested brackets.

```
import re
print(re.split(r',(?![^[]*\])', 'word1[a,b,c],word2[e,f,g],word3'))
```

outputs `['word1[a,b,c]', 'word2[e,f,g]', 'word3']`

http://ideone.com/7vIwFM